# jQuery ui datepicker in direction rtl page - position issue

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, right-to-left

I am working on an Arabic (rtl direction) form with a ui calendar for selecting dob. using jquery.ui.datepicker.js

There is no `left` or `right` style coming from script to position the calendar near the input location. `top` value is correct.

Now the calendar is positioned to the right of the page.

[image]

It works fine in the ltr version.

Do I need any additional fixes for rtl page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **[this link](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-isRTL)** you can try it as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hnu0r78y/)**

Initialize the `datepicker` with the `isRTL` option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  isRTL: true
});
```

Get or set the `isRTL` option, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var isRTL = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "isRTL" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "isRTL", true );
```